# Have a window showing on both screens in a dual monitor setup

Tags: gnome, xfce, multi-monitor

While presenting using a projector, is it possible to have the laptop screen showing all the open windows (including my presentation notes) and the projector showing only those windows I want the audience to see (a pdf file, a document)?

Is there a way to "duplicate" a window on both screens while keeping other windows showing only on the main screen?

This would permit me to switch between windows while presenting without exposing my notes, etc. to the audience.

I use mostly Gnome as my preferred desktop environment but use XFCE occasionally. However, I'm willing to test out other DEs if need be.

Comment: I know that `clfswm` can do this (Common Lisp FullScreen WM), but I understand that this is not qualifying as an answer to your question.  Thus just for the log… ;)  Though, I seriously doubt that this is a usage scenario provided by Gnome. :(

Comment: I found a sort of workaround. If I convert my texts to pdf, I can use Okular's presentation mode to have the text open in my main window and the presentation text on the projector.

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to use vnc for this. I would run the presentation in the Xvnc session (probably on :1) and open two viewers as a shared session, one full screen for the projector the other windowed on the main screen. Note that this only works if the main screen is higher resolution than the projector unless you use scaling.

A second approach would be a dual seat setup with either vnc.so or X11vnc running on the projector's seat and viewing it on the other monitor. The same restrictions about resolution still apply, and dual seats tend to be difficult to do, especially on laptops. Another variant is to add another remote display instead of two monitors connected to the laptop, for example if your projector accepts HDMI signals a raspberry pi to drive the projector and a crossover cable might do the trick, or if you don't mind the crypto issues with wifi could allow a wireless presentation.